# I'm assuming the C code below does something.But it is not working as my assumption.Please check what is wrong in my assumption?

Tags: c

The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
   char arr[]={'a','b','c','d'};
   char *i,*j,*k;
   i=&arr[1];
   j=&arr[2];
   k=&arr[3];
   printf("%s %p %p %p %s\n",(j-i)'i,j,k,(k-i));
}
```

1. When i try to compile this the error shown is that %s expects (char *) 
   but it is(i.e (j-i))is int.but i think i defined j&i as char pointer then how does
   (j-i)becomes an integer.
2. If i use %d instead of %s the answer for (j-i) comes to 1 and (k-i) comes to 2 which
   is actually the element difference.how does this happen.
3. When i print address of i,j,k as above using %p it does the correct addresses 
   but what happens why cant 2 addresses be subtracted to give their difference in bytes?

Please give your view point?

edit: Adding code for second part of question about pointer diffs:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

main() 
{ 
    int arr[]={10,20,34,65}; 
    int *i,*j,*k; 
    i=&arr[1]; 
    j=&arr[2]; 
    k=&arr[3]; 
    printf("%d %p %p %p %d\n",(j-i),i,j,k,(k-i)); 
}
```

Comment: Read on *Pointer Arithmetic*.

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: @Bart that (j-i) should show the difference between jth and ith element in bytes.

Comment: @THEPARADOX and it does.

Comment: @THEPARADOX If that is what you're expecting, then what is so surprising about the result? (Please note the small typo in your code where you have a `'` instead of a comma)

Comment: BUT If i use integer array still the (j-i) a comes to difference between elements but in that case it should be (j-i)*4.

Comment: Can you then show us the code for that case? Because it should output what you expect it does. Unless I'm not following what you're getting at.

Comment: 'code' #include<stdio.h>
main()
{
   int arr[]={10,20,34,65};
   int *i,*j,*k;
   i=&arr[1];
   j=&arr[2];
   k=&arr[3];
   printf("%d %p %p %p %d\n",(j-i)'i,j,k,(k-i));
}

Comment: I edited the post above to add the new code, as it's pretty unreadable as a comment.

Comment: "I'm assuming the C code below does something."  No, it won't compile. You have syntax errors that Bart pointed out.

Comment: @josh when i compile the code it gives no syntax error but the answer is not what i'm assuming.for instance if i have an integer array of five elements then the difference between the adress of 1st element and 5th element should be 16 bytes but answer that comes up  is 4 and if want difference between 0th and 5th element answer i get is 5 instead of 20.i would like to know why?

Comment: Did you read the comment from KingsIndian? _Pointer Arithmetic_ doesn't return the distance in _bytes_ but distance in the _number of elements_. Please search for the term _Pointer Arithmetic_, there are many related questions and answers.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks.this was what i needed to know that it does return bytes but element difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has bothered to write actual answer:

1. Substracting pointer from another gives difference of pointers, as integer.
2. Difference of pointer values is in *size of pointed type* (which is obvious when you think what `intptr++` does).
3. To get difference in bytes, multiply by size of type, for example `(sizeof int)*(j-i)`